# How to correctly encode responses from an AD search?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, active-directory

I search in an MS Active Directory with Python and I stumbled upon an issue with the encoding of an answer I get.

I use the code below to recursively go through the AD

```
import ldap
import pickle

class SearchAD():
    def __init__(self):
        self.l = ldap.initialize("ldap://ldap.example.com")
        self.l.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
        self.l.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)

        bind = self.l.simple_bind_s("user", "password")
        self.base = "DC=example,DC=com"
        self.all = list()

    def searchmgr(self, criteria, m):
        print criteria
        m += 1
        attributes = ['dn', 'title']
        result = self.l.search_s(self.base, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, u'manager='+criteria, attributes)
        for u in result:
            cn, t = u
            if cn is not None and "Disabled Users" not in cn and t.get('title'):
                self.all.append({'dn': cn, 'title': t['title'][0], 'm': m})
                self.searchmgr(cn, m)


s = SearchAD()
s.searchmgr("CN=EXAMPLE Top,DC=example,DC=com", 0)
with open("dir.pickle", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(s.all, f)
```

and get

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position
>   16: ordinal not in range(128)

when calling

```
result = self.l.search_s(self.base, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, 'manager='+criteria, attributes)
```

The search works fine (I get the expected output via the `print`) until the string `'CN=DOE Marie-h\xc3\xa9l\xc3\xa8ne,OU=User Accounts,...'` which translates to `'CN=DOE Marie-hélène,OU=User Accounts,...'`.

This is expected as [AD returns its results in UTF-8](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961766.aspx)

I therefore tried to `.encode('utf-8')` the string and use

```
result = self.l.search_s(self.base, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, u'manager='+criteria.encode('utf-8'), attributes)
```

but I get the same error.

How should I handle the result returned by AD?

Comment: Could you clarify whether you cannot process results returned by search_s method, or the error occurs when you're trying to call search_s method (no data are returned)?

Comment: @MichałKomorowski: the error occurs while `self.l.search_s()` is running on a piece of tree which contains the problematic entry. In other words, since this is a recursive function, `self.l.search_s()` is called many times and the calls are successful until it digs up to the problematic entry. Hope this is clearer now.